# How to get content from another page in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I want to display some pages of my Jekyll website in my Home page. How can I accomplish this?

Currently I am trying to do the following:

```
{% assign sorted = (site.pages | sort: 'order_home') %}
{% for my_page in sorted %}
    {% if my_page.order_home %}    
        {{ my_page }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

However, what happens is that content is exhibited in the following form:

```
{"layout"=>"page", "title"=>"Blog", "permalink"=>"/blog/", "comments"=>false, "order_nav"=>4, "order_home"=>3, "content"=>"
\n{% for category in site.categories reversed %}\n
\n {% capture category_name %}{{ category | first }}{% endcapture %}\n
\n\n
{{ category_name }}
\n \n {% for post in site.categories[category_name] %}\n
\n
{{post.title}}
\n
\n {% endfor %}\n
\n{% endfor %}\n
\n", "dir"=>"/blog/", "name"=>"posts.md", "path"=>"posts.md", "url"=>"/blog/"}
```

I would like to make the content appear as if it was the rendered page itself, with the {{...}} blocks correctly processed. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you do `{{ my_page.content }}`?

Comment: this look like an encoding problem. Check that all your files are utf-8 NO BOM.

Comment: my_page.content outputs the following:

{% for category in site.categories reversed %}
{% capture category_name %}{{ category | first }}{% endcapture %}
{{ category_name }}
{% for post in site.categories[category_name] %}
{{post.title}}

{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}

@KevinWorkman

Comment: @DavidJacquel all pages are encoded with UTF-8. The problem is not the \n or anything related to encoding, but rather the {{ }} blocks not being processed by Jekyll

Comment: It's good to have a code repository url in order to help debug.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.content` to `my_page`. This results in the following code:

```
{% assign sorted = (site.pages | sort: 'order_home') %}
{% for my_page in sorted %}
    {% if my_page.order_home %}    
        {{ my_page.content }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```